# Using lookup value to filter a split form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

thanks in advance for any help

I'm using a macro to perform a filter on a split form by taking a value from a text box.

Everything works fine, except for fields that use a lookup to get there value. Unfortunately I cant figure out how to search the shown value in the field as opposed to the bound column.

Should I use dLookUp? I cant seem to get it to work

Any help appreciated

Cheers

Noel

Answer (score 0):

This was glaringly obvious.

Just needed to add the apropriate field from the related tables to the form.

If I could delete this quetion I would!

Comment: You should also not use lookup fields stored in tables: http://mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm